# Intents or directly accessing a public variable of a different class

Tags: android, android-intent

I noticed that most programmers in Android use an Intent or broadcast receiver to send a short text message from one class to another class.

If I am using a utility class that does not extend any other class like Activity or Service, why not just directly access the variable in the utility class like this.

```
 UtilityClass utility = new UtilityClass();
 String gotIt = utility.theOtherVariable; // direct access to variable in other class
```

is there anything wrong with doing it this way?   I would rather do this than use an intent or broadcast receiver to send the small text message from the utility class to the Activity class.

EDIT

in addition to the instance of the class, you can also make the variable static that your are passing from one activity to another.  in either case I don't see any value to using an extra of intent or broadcast receiver to pass information from one Activity to another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of-course you can use that And even it is good practice that you are using your own data structure but it is depend on need and scenario.
For example suppose you are receiving data from gps and you need that data in your app at some 5-6 places then its good to design one class and store the gps data in the variable of the class and access it where ever you want in your ways

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course its good thing to make public class and keep your where Variable and Function as publicly so you can use in further activity.But that you all ready know that this type of function and variable  will be use in some activity.

Where Intent is like Good and easy way to switching data one activity to anther activity.like if you don't want to use some variable more then single next activity then it will useful. More Impotent use of Intent is Return activity Result. like if you want to perform action but its depend on next activity then Intent will use as powerful tool to achieve your task.

Short and Sweet : It's Depend on Requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UtilityClass utility = new UtilityClass();
```

Initialized Utilityclass in Your `Activity`.Use Utilityclass object you will get all values in your utliityclass.

Example,

```
public class UtilityClass{
public static string gotIt = "value";
}  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
UtilityClass utility = new UtilityClass();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.xml);
 String str =  utility.gotIt;
}
```